# Laravel How to store multiple JSON data to an array so that all data can be accepted by controller

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I have a project which I can add multiple data. ex: I will add 2 names and it will be display on the next table. Also I converted each data into json so that I can pass it to the controller. Now my problem is that every time I click the check button the controller can only read the last data I inputted. Is there any way to get all data from table and pass it to controller? Here's my script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit-button").click(function(){
      var data = $('#form_id').serializeArray();
      var obj = {};
      for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
          obj[data[i].name] = data[i].value;
      }
      var json_text = JSON.stringify(obj);

      $('#submit-button').after('<pre>' + json_text + '</pre>'); //shows only to determine if its working.
      $('table.footable tbody').append('<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="request" value='+json_text+'></td> <td>'+obj['firstname']+'</td><td>'+obj['lastname']+'</td></tr>');
      $("#firstname").val('');
      $("#lastname").val('');
    })
  })
 </script>
<form id="form_id">
    <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="" placeholder="Max" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" />
    <label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" value="" placeholder="Max" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" />
    <input type="button" value="submit" id="submit-button" />
</form>

<div id="table">
<h2>List of all person</h2>
<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"> 
<table class="footable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-class="expand"> First Name </th>
            <th> Last Name </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-sm">Check</button>
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hey could you add the code that you have on the controller?

Comment: it seems that you are overriding your obj every time you submit. declare your obj as global variable and it should save both names rather than one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to limited characters in comment. I will post my latest issue here.

I dont know if it is correct. Here's my latest code

Input example:

```
Firstname   Lastname
Kerwin      Manisan
Ivan        Sanchez
```

Javascript

```
$('table.footable tbody').append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="firstname[]" value="'+obj['firstname']+'"></td><td><input type="text" name="lastname[]" value="'+obj['lastname']+'"></td></tr>');
```

Controller:

```
public function test(Request $request){
    return $data = $request->input('firstname');
}
```

Result:

```
["Kerwin","Ivan"]
```

Sad to say the output that I need is something like this.

```
[{"firstname":"Kerwin","lastname":"Manisan"},{"firstname":"Ivan" , "lastname":"Sanchez"}]
```

**EDIT:
Problem solved.** I used count to determine how many rows and then used loop to show the rows.

Controller:

```
public function test(Request $request){

        $count = count($request->input('firstname'));
        for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
            $data[] = array('firstname' => $request->input('firstname')[$i], 'lastname' => $request->input('lastname')[$i]);
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing all the JSON data as text in the hidden field, create a new input for each new name. Instead you would add hidden inputs in your java script which would result in something like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="name[0]">

<input type="hidden" name="name[1]">
```

In your controller you can use the following (based on using request laravel5)

```
public function myFunction(Request $request) {
    foreach($request['name']  as $name) 
    {
        //do something with your name variable
    } 

}
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this and give feedback after.

Comment: `public function json(Request $data){  
   foreach ($data['name'] as $name) {
    return $name;
  }
}`

I followed you advice and now I got this error in controller
Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request as array

Comment: Sorry that's my fault. Try $request->input('name')  instead. I'll take a better look when I get to work

Comment: I've tried returning $request->input('firstname'); and the output is the last firstname I inputted but when I tried foreach ($request->input('name') as $name) { return $name;  } I got this error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()". I don't know what's the problem where for me it's correct.

Comment: I found out that the attribute name must be in array. Now there's no error but still my problem is not solve.